# Filter jobs by inventory

Tags: ansible, awx

I'm using Ansible AWX and I'd like to find all jobs that were done for a specific inventory , I can do that by going to the inventory and then in the "completed jobs" tab, but is there a way to do that directly from the jobs page ? I can see there's some key filter such as "created, modified, name, description, unified_job_template, launch_type" and only found  "inventory_update" related to inventory